# Install/Remove Language show only English, no other choice

Tags: 12.10, language-support

So my question is, when I want to choose other language to install, it shows only English installed (checked), but what I can see in the other posts, there is a list of languages that allows user to choose.

I am a totally new to Linux. What should I do to get the list of languages to appear)? Why is this happen, is it because I've skipped the language packs during the installation?

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you running? In 12.10, under language support, there is a "install/Remove Languages" option.

Comment: Yes, thats the place i meant, but there are no other languages for me to add, except English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something appears to be missing.  It's not the fact that you might have skipped language support at the time of installation as I have an EeePC that I installed without a network connection and I can indeed get to a full language selection screen by clicking the <kbd>Install/Remove Languages</kbd> button as per the instructions below.

The only things I can think for you to do at the moment is install the languages individually as suggested by Mowgli, or try to re-install the gnome language selector and see if that fixes the problem:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install language-selector-gnome
```

You then need to open the language selector from system settings and click on the button <kbd>Install/Remove Languages</kbd>.  You will get a separate window that opens where you can select additional languages to install.

[image: to get to the language selector]

Comment: yup, i know this, but there are no any other languages for me to install except English that is installed by default, see the print screen :(

Comment: Try re-installing the gnome language selector as per my edit above.

Comment: @fabricator4 It's give me this message - 'Reinstallation of language-selector-gnome is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
'

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the options are not coming up. A work-around is to try install languages from the terminal.

The following command will list language packs that can be installed:

```
apt-cache search language-pack
```

The packs can be install by entering (for French):

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-fr-base
sudo apt-get install language-pack-fr
```

Replace 'fr' by the language code of your choice found by running the very first command.

Answer (score 1):

I already resolve it, the main reason why the options are not showing up is because i didn't update it(i skipped updates during installation), so I just simply type in:

`sudo apt-get update`

after finish update, the languages magically appear, Forgive the Stupid me. D:

Answer (score 0):

Go to system settings, in system settings, go to keyboard layout.
in language tab, select any one with bracket. 
For example:

```
Chinese
English
English(Australia)
English(Canada)
English(NZ)
English(UK)
```